# php image upload issue , video extensions does not return error

Tags: php, html, image, upload

php code :

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $errors = array();
    $allowed_ext = array ('jpg','gif','png','jpeg');

    $file_name = $_FILES ['image']['name'];
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = end ($file_ext);
    $file_ext = strtolower($file_ext);
    echo $file_ext;
    $file_size = $_FILES ['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES ['image']['tmp_name'];

    if (!in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext)) {
        $errors[] = "File extension is not allowed.";
    }

    if ($file_size > 2097152 ) {
        $errors[] = "File size is greater than 2 megabytes.";
    }

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        foreach ($errors AS $error) {
            echo $error . "<br />";
        }
    } else {
        $file_name = md5(microtime()).".".$file_ext;
        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $avatar_folder.$file_name)) {
        }
    }
}

?>
```

html code :

```
<div id="form_part">
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <input type="FILE" name="image">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </p>

</form>
</div> <!-- end form_part -->
```

Now , The problem is as you can i see i am specifying the images file type in array to allow specific extensions to be uploaded and prevent others and return error message if file type does not exist in this array but when i test this with video files the file is not uploaded to the upload directory but the error message does not display although it is displayed when i upload txt,rar,pdf, etc..... , Why is that and how can i fix it ?

Comment: flv , avi , mp4 , vob , ts files , This is the files i tested.

Comment: Might be a PHP upload error. Try echoing $_FILES['image']['error']. Here is the list of possible errors [link]http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
$allowed_exts = array('.png','.gif','.jpg','.jpeg') ; // Our Allowed Extentions

$errors       = array() ;                             // Our Error Array

$file_name    =  $_FILES['image']['name'] ;           
$file_size    =  $_FILES['image']['size'] ;

$file_ext     = strtolower(strrchr($file_name,'.')); // File Extention

if(!in_array($file_ext,$allowed_exts))
        {
          array_push($errors,'NoT Allowed');
        }
elseif($file_size > 2097152)
        {
          array_push($errors,'More Than 2 mb');
        }



if(count($errors) > 0)
        {
          var_dump($errors) ;
        }
else
        {

          $new_name      = substr(md5(rand().time()),0,8).$file_ext ;

          $upload        = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$avatar_folder.$new_name )  ;


          if($upload)
                         {
                           echo 'Image Uploaded ';
                         }
          else
                         {
                           var_dump($errors) ;
                         }


        }
```

Comment: Did not work , I just replaced the $file_ext part but it does not work , when i try to upload any image file i got file extension not allowed !

Comment: ohhh sorry , it is working now , i forgot to add '.' in array elements , but the same issue is still exist ! when i try to upload .avi file for example it is not uploaded but no error message displayed !

Answer (score 0):

write test.php and place this code:

```
phpinfo();
```

This code will print server configuration page. Look for "upload_max_filesize" value. It tells how big file can be uploaded.

If this value is to small, most of the hosting companies allow to change it in .htaccess file using following line:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
```

By the way, your code does not check for errors. At the top, you need to add lines:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   //do your code
} else {
   echo $_FILES['audio']['error'];
   //Error messages explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
}
```

Comment: i am checking for filesize and file type errors , what this line above is for ?

Comment: So what is the error code? What does this line result?

echo $_FILES['audio']['error'];